# fn key for setting brightness in ubuntu 14.04 lts is NOT working for Asus X550LD

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, brightness

I am facing the above problem only for Brightness Control. Rest all the Controls with fn key are working. I dont want to create new Shortcuts like CTRL+F5 or CTRL+F6. I want that it should happen with fn key only (as displayed on my keyboard).

Please help me on this....

Answer (score 0):

Try adding acpi_backlight=vendor as a boot option. To do that, open a terminal window, and run

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Locate this line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`.

Edit it to look like this: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"`

Save the file, then, in a terminal, run `sudo update-grub`.

Reboot, and check if the brightness keys work.